# Using WebBrowser in IE9 causing ObjectDisposedException

Tags: html, browser, internet-explorer-9, webbrowser-control, activexobject

It sounds silly but I would like to know why it doesn't work.

In Visual Studio 2012 I have created an ActiveX object (.dll) with a WebBrowser control in it. It worked fine when calling by other Windows control (for example Windows Form Application), a webpage could be opened successfully within a Windows form.

Since ActiveX object could be embedded in IE, I created a html file and embedded the ActiveX object using the  tag. When the html file is opened and called the WebBrowser control, an ObjectDisposedException happened.

I am not familiar how IE and ActiveX object works, so what is actually happened under? To me it of course seems funny to use an IE brower to call the WebBrowser which use IE underneath (sorry for bad English writing here, I am not good at expressing things like this). It would be grateful if anyone could explain what is underneath. Thanks in advance!